# How to show value of baseline at v-axis with Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I add a baseline to v-axis in Google Chart.

```
vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity', baseline: 20, baselineColor: 'red'
    }
```

[image]

And I want to show the value of the baseline like this.

[image]

How can I do it?

This is the whole code in jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ztn5fmnw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need a few more options to get exactly as the posted image

but first, need to add another column to the data table
no data is needed in the new column,
just add it after the orignal data has been loaded

```
data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
```

the new series will be assigned to a second y-axis (on the right side)
this will allow customization of the second y-axis

```
series: {
  1: {
    targetAxisIndex: 1,     // <-- assign y1 to second y-axis
    visibleInLegend: false  // <-- hide from legend
  }
},
```

next, both y-axis will need the same range
use `vAxis.viewWindow` to set the range for both

```
vAxis: {
  title: 'Popularity', baseline: 20, baselineColor: 'red',
  viewWindow: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }
},
```

then use the `vAxes` option to customize only the second y-axis
use `ticks` to add the value of the baseline

```
vAxes: {
  1: {
    textStyle: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    ticks: [20]
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);
  data.addColumn('number', 'y1');

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity', baseline: 20, baselineColor: 'red',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      1: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'red'
        },
        ticks: [20]
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```